# Javascript Regex Replace String with Special Character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string with value = `"[1] a [2] b [3] c"` in Javascript. I would like to replace it to `"a b c"`.

My question is how to do it in Javascript by using Regex?

I have tried the following but no luck:

```
var strText = "[1] a [2] b [3] c";
var strTextReplaced = strText.replace(new RegExp("\[/d\] ", ""), "");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regular expression `/\[\d+\]/g`:

```
> var value = "[1] a [2] b [3] c";
> value.replace(/\[\d+\]/g, '')
" a  b  c"
```

- `\d` instead of `/d`.
- Escape `[` and `]`.

Use `/\[\d+\]\s*/` if you want remove extra spaces.

Comment: I'd use `/\[\d+\]\s*/` to remove extra spaces.

Comment: @M42, I mentioned that. Thank you.

Comment: rigth. I give you +1.

Comment: I think that last asterisk should be a plus. The original request said they wanted to match '[1] ', and this proposition will also match '[1]' without the trailing space (although given it's a greedy match, you'll likely not notice this during testing).

Answer (score 0):

It's `\d` instead of `/d`, and you need to escape the special characters with `\` as well.  Also, you need the "g" or global flag which allows more than one replacement.

In JavaScript the `\` has special meaning.  So you need to escape it as well.

```
strText.replace(new RegExp("\\[\\d\\]", "g"), "")
```

Because of the nusiance of that, JavaScript has this shorthand version of the above.

```
strText.replace(/\[\d\]/g, "")
```

Technically you only need to escape the `[`, but not the `]`.

```
strText.replace(/\[\d]/g, "")
```